# In vim script, how to tell if a setting has been specified in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

In a vim plugin, how can I tell if a user has already set a variable in their .vimrc file?

For instance, I have in `.vimrc`:

```
set shiftwidth=2
```

Then I load a plugin that has

```
set shiftwidth=3
```

So I think to modify the plugin like so:

```
if !exists("shiftwidth")
  set shiftwidth=3
endif
```

But when I load up a new vim window with the revised plugin loaded, my tabs are still set to `3` and not `2`.

How can I make it so that it only sets `shiftwidth=3` unless otherwise specified in `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands should show where `shiftwidth` was set:

```
:set verbose=15
:set shiftwidth
:set verbose=0
```

If you want to programmatically do something with that info you'd need to `redirect` the verbose output and parse it for what you want:

```
:redir => myvariable
:set verbose=15
:set shiftwidth
:set verbose=0
:redir END
```

`myvariable` will now have text that would otherwise have been printed to screen.

**REVISED ANSWER**
Here is a way I think you could do what you clarify in your comments.

Add a last line to user's vimrc to save the current value of shiftwidth to a global variable.  The value will be saved before any plugins are loaded, unless plugins are explicitly sourced in the vimrc before the last line.  You can then reset shiftwidth to this value in your own plugin.

```
[everything in vimrc comes before this line]
:let g:vimrc_shiftwidth = &shiftwidth
```

You can programmatically add this line with something like the `write >> [file]` command.  Presumably you would include a comment indicating what plugin had added this command to the vimrc.  Also, I don't think this would capture the correct value, e.g., in case where user uses exrc option and sets shiftwidth in a different vimrc.  All in all, still not recommended.

Comment: The verbose output of `:set shiftwidth` confirms that my plugin was where the value for `shiftwidth` was last set, but you didn't answer my question about how to modify my plugin so that it uses the value specified in `.vimrc` if it's set.

Comment: @neezer -- Sorry, I didn't read close enough.  Verbose will only tell you where it was last set.  If a user has changed the value set since startup that won't help you.  I think you'd need to open the vimrc file and search for the line that sets `shiftwidth`, which could be `set sw=...`, `set shiftwidth=...`, `let &sw=...`, or `let &shiftwidth=...`.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz - Hmm, I feel like there must be a better way than trolling through the `.vimrc` file each time the plugin is loaded. I'm not concerned about if a user changes it after the plugin is loaded, I'm just trying to get it right on load, eg: open a file with ftype to load the plugin => have `shiftwitdth` equal setting in `.vimrc`, unless there is no setting in `.vimrc`, in which case `shiftwidth` would equal the plugin default.

Comment: @neezer Why do you need this at all? There is no way to tell whether setting was set in the vimrc other then parsing redirected output (use `silent set shiftwidth?` to make it not shown to user). But there is a problem: there can be more then one vimrc: see `:h .vimrc`.

Comment: @ZyX - I'd just like to have the plugin honor whatever value the user set for `shiftwidth` rather than specifying it's own value. I like my tabs set for 2 spaces, so that's what I set in `.vimrc`. However, loading this plugin resets that to 3 spaces, and the comments in the code for the plugin say something to the effect of "set default tab width". It's frustrating for me because I've already set the default to what I want: 2 spaces. I was looking for a way to have the plugin honor **my** preference rather than impose its own.

Comment: @ZyX - (continued) Since I have my plugins installed via pathogen and git submodules, I wanted to patch the plugin with logic that would honor the user's choice of `shiftwidth`, but in case there wasn't any specified by the user, set a default... thus my question.

Comment: @neezer It is usually handled by user himself by using `after/` directory or by just not specifying this option in the plugin. Though you can parse `:setglobal shiftwidth?` (it is a bit better then `:set` as options in vimrc are usually global and global options must not be overriden by filetype plugins), there is no reliable way to tell what was set by user and what was not: you don't know whether or not user cares about `sw` defined in plugin superShiftWidth, you can't tell why user has not altered the defaults (he may not know about `sw` or be happy with defaults), same for system vimrc ...

Comment: @neezer ... If I used plugin with some complicated empirics used for (not) setting some option I would consider it too smart, pretending to be smarter then me. Do you like software that is pretending to be smarter then you? / I suggest you change it instead: If it is a filetype plugin it should locally set `sw` if there is a reason (like common documented coding standarts) and not touch it at all if there is not. If it is something like a collection of good tricks, then either change it, leave as-is or use better determined algorithm (for example, some global option like `g:setOptionalOpts`).

Comment: @ZyX - Ok, this is quickly becoming a mountain when it is really only a molehill. :) I don't see any solid reason why [the script in question](https://github.com/vim-scripts/php.vim-html-enhanced) feels it should set `sw=3` (because I don't like software that's smarter than me), but after this discussion, I'll just remember to update it manually whenever I update the git repo. Incidentally, if you know of any alternative plugins that do the same thing, I'm all ears.

Comment: @neezer 1. You can use `:h after-directory`. 2. `git pull` does merge automatically, so I don't see why you say you will update manually. 3. Why don't you bug author? Filetype-specific plugins **must** not change global options (that is what `:set` does and why `:setlocal` is prefered). Indent script should not change local shiftwidth, it is not its business. 4. You can always maintain a fork of this plugin with functionality you require. Normal workflow is to create a fork, do changes, push them to the fork and send a pull request to plugin author ...

Comment: ... though last is not applicable here as it is a repost of vim.org plugins to github.

Comment: 5. It would not solve your problem since you still have to modify plugin you don't have access for (or have author agreed to release that modified version if you find an answer and refused to remove `set sw`?).